# HTML5 input slider difficult on smarphone smartphone

Tags: html

I am currently having problems with the HTML5 input[type=range]. It is fine in chrome on the desktop, but has some issues on smartphones. It is difficult to change the slider with big fingers. Plus you can't really slide, you can only click the range input.

How have you integrated this in your HTML5 websites?

Answer (score 0):

The HTML5 input[type="range"] shows a slider that works great on desktops.

On touchscreen phones you have to tap; not slide. Except on iOS, where you first have to tap the slider button and then you can slide it.

If you want to build a better slider on smartphones you should probably take a look at jQuery UI or some kind of mobile framework (jQtouch, jquery mobile, etc). They will optimize the output based on the device.